# How to create a new scene without errors?

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm relatively new to Java and I'm having difficulty with running a program. Now, as a heads up, this is a homework assignment. The problem is to create a program with the output as "Welcome to Java" in a circle.

Here is my code thus far:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.text.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Characters extends Application {
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Pane canvas = new Pane(); 
        canvas.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;"); 
        canvas.setPrefSize(200, 200); // set size of pane
        Font f = Font.font("Times New Roman", FontWeight.BOLD, 35);

    String s = "Welcome to Java"; 
    String c; 

    double d = 25.0, x = 10.0, y = 20.0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

        c = "" + s.charAt(i); 
        Text t = new Text(x, y, c); 

        t.setFont(f); 
        t.setRotate(d); 
        d++; 
        x++;
        y++;
        canvas.getChildren().add(t); 
    }

    Scene scene = new Scene(root,500, 500, Color.BLACK); 
    stage.setTitle("Characters around a circle");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

I keep receiving an error at `Scene scene = new Scene(root,500, 500, Color.BLACK);` and I haven't been able to find a solution. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: "[The application must specify the root Node for the scene graph by setting the root property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html)."  You never declared `root`.  Try something along the lines of `Group root = new Group();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`root` is not declared anywhere in your program. Try adding `canvas` to a layout and add the layout to the scene.

```
BorderPane rootLayout = new BorderPane();
rootLayout.getChildren().add(canvas);
Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout, 500,500);
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, I implemented your suggestion, however, I got another error, making me remove "Color.BLACK"

Comment: yes..sorry about that..I have edited the answer..Copy-paste error :)
Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: So the error is gone, thanks!

However, when I run the program, all I see is a black floodlight, not "Welcome To Java" written in a circle.

Comment: remove canvas.setStyle(). The font is black and canvas background is black. So you will not be able to see anything. Also, d++,x++,y++ is not sufficient to print the letters in circle. You might have to work around for that. setRotate() will not change the position of the characters, it just rotates the character in same position.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/57749/rotating-text-in-circular-pattern-using-javafx
This link might help.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like `root` (the first parameter in your constructor) is defined anywhere in the scope.

In the docs they do this:

```
Group root = new Group();
Scene s = new Scene(root, 300, 300, Color.BLACK);
```

But I'm not sure if you want to put in the `canvas` somewhere.

Something to note (copy-pasted from the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html)):

> The application must specify the root Node for the scene graph by setting the root property. If a Group is used as the root, the contents of the scene graph will be clipped by the scene's width and height and changes to the scene's size (if user resizes the stage) will not alter the layout of the scene graph. If a resizable node (layout Region or Control is set as the root, then the root's size will track the scene's size, causing the contents to be relayed out as necessary.

Basically, if you want the components to be forced within the `Scene`, it looks like you want a `Group`. If you want the components to change the size of the `Scene` then use a resizable node (e.g. `Region` or `Control`).